# How to create dynamic captcha using vbscript

Tags: asp-classic, captcha

What generally occurs in the captcha's is that a single word is displayed and the user has to just enter that word in to validate the captcha. But in this case what I want is that my captcha would consist of a slogan(that is a sentence),and on each time the computer would ask like...
Enter the first word in the slogan..
Next time it asks,Enter the third word and so on randomly...
Can anyone provide me an idea how t d this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I have created CAPTCHAs in Classic ASP in the past. When the form is displayed to a user I generate a random number and also a question and answer.

The random number is used as the name for a session variable that stores the answer to the question. I also add a hidden field with the value of the random number. This random number allows one user to display multiple forms in different windows/tabs without using the same session variable. It also means that anyone trying to hack the page must retrieve the page before they can post to it so makes it a little more difficult to hack.

When the user submits the form I get the hidden field value, then get the answer stored in the session variable, and the session variable is removed so that a 'bot can't get multiple attempts at guessing an answer. Then the user's answer can be compared with what the user entered. If they don't get it correct then the form is displayed again, with new random number and answer generated.

The code when the form is generated would be something like this:

```
'get your question and answer
strQuestion = "My question"
strAnswer = "answer"

Randomize
strVarName = Int((999999 - 100000 + 1) * Rnd() + 100000)
Session(strVarName) = strAnswer



<input type="hidden" name="varname" value="<%= strVarName %>" />
```

The code when the form is sbumitted qould be something like this:

```
strVarName = Request.Form("varname")
strUserAnswer = Request.Form("answer")
strRealAnswer = Session(strVarName)
Session.Items.Remove(strVarName)

If strUserAnswer <> strRealAnswer Then
    'invalid response
    'show form again with new answer and session
End If
```